# How can reference the last item in a list in a Django template? {{ list.-1.key }}

Tags: django, django-templates

if I have a variable in the context of unknown length, for example;
`list=[{'key':'A'},{'key':'B'},{'key':'C'}]`

How can I get the last object? `{{ list.0.key }}` works for the first, but `{{ list.-1.key }}` gives;
`Could not parse the remainder: '-1.key' from 'list.-1.key'`

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Thanks everyone for you help, it lead me to the realisation that I can use the [with tag](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/templates/builtins/#with).

```
{% with list|last as last %}
    {{ last.key }}
{% endwith %}
```

Comment: Also works with slice if you want something other than the last element: `{% with list|slice:":-2" as my_var %}`

Comment: Error: Negative indexing is not supported. Django v.1.7

Answer (score 48):

Use the [`last`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#last) template tag:

```
{{ value|last }}
```

> If value is the list `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']`, the output will be the string `"d"`.

Comment: `{{ list|last.key }}` => `Could not parse the remainder: '.key' from 'list|last.key'`

Comment: I spent a whopping half an hour looking for this. Thanks! FYI this seems to be pretty much the only way to get the last element of an xrange object in Python 2. `make_list` and `slice` filters and their combinations all fail for different reasons.

Comment: most updated solution and compatible with multiple assignments on the `with` block

Answer (score 9):

In my case I find this solution: `{{object_list.last.id}}`
very useful on expression like this: `{% url 'my-url' object_list.first.id object_list.last.id %}`

Answer (score 7):

You can mark the last forloop by the following tags

```
{% if forloop.last %} ... {% endif %}
```

and add you special desire inside the tags.

Answer (score 1):

without with, will be:

```
{% set last = list|last %}
{{ last.key }}
```

Answer (score 1):

It worked for my by simply counting the number of records inside the views.py file using the built in function count() and then check if the forloop.counter != total_count then add and

---

```
{% if forloop.counter != total_jobs %}
    <hr>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Your code does not look like a solution to the question: "How can I get the last object?". Please add the code which shows how one can get the last object.

Comment: @PeterHuber it's simple you can simply send the total count of the objects and then check it in the for loop if the for loop counter matches that number then print it.

Answer (score -3):

Use this piece of code in your template:

```
{{ list|slice:":-1".items.0.0 }}
```

Comment: `{{ list|slice:":-1".key }}` => `Could not parse the remainder: '.key' from 'list|slice:":-1".key'`

Comment: Could not parse the remainder: '.items.0.0' from 'list|slice:":-1".items.0.0'

Comment: The `slice` template tag also doesn't support negative indices.