# Last element in django template list variable

Tags: django

I would like to know how to filter out the last element of a list variable from the context object.

```
{% for d in data %}
    {{ d }},
{% endfor %}
```

I don't want to have the `,` after the last element. Thank you.

**NOTE**: This is just a hypothetical example. I know we can use the join filter to achieve the same thing here

Comment: For reference, if you need *only* the last element you can use the `last` filter, like so: `data|last` - see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4730600/how-can-reference-the-last-item-in-a-list-in-a-django-template-list-1-key

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Do you mean -

```
{% for d in data %}
    {% if forloop.last %}
        {{ d }}
    {% else %}
        {{ d }},
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

have a look at the [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#for) on template for loops

Comment: If you're using [jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/), this can be accomplished with `{% for d in data %}{%if d == data|last %}{{ d }} {% else %}{{ d }}, {% endif %}{% endfor %}`

See [last built-in function](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#last)

Answer (score 13):

Use `{{ data|join:", " }}`, it does exactly what you need.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#join

Comment: Thank you. I knew the join filter. The example above was just a cooked up version to demonstrate what I mean.

Answer (score 11):

Or you can try this as well -

```
{% for d in data %}
    {{ d }} {% if not forloop.last %},{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

have a look at the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/templates/builtins/#for) on template for loops