# How can I show only last entry in django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I'm using Django 1.5.1. I have a ImageModel for top of my first page.
How can I show only last entry of this model?

```
#model.py
    class Vitrin(models.Model):
        title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        image = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'images/vitrin/')
        date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)  

#views.py
def index(request):
    categories = Category.objects.all()[:5]
    pages = Page.objects.all()[:5]
    vitrins = Vitrin.objects.all().reverse()[0]
    return render(request, 'gallery/index.html', {'categories': categories, 'pages':pages, 'vitrins': vitrins})   

#index.html
    <div class='vitrin'>
            {% for vitrin in vitrins %}
                <img src="{{ vitrin.image.url|last }}" height="550">
            {% endfor %}
    </div>
```

But I get error: **'Vitrin' object is not iterable**

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/
Django Version: 1.5.1
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
'Vitrin' object is not iterable
Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py in render, line 147
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was trying to iterate a single object in my template, which caused the error. This returns a single object: `vitrins = Vitrin.objects.all().reverse()[0]`
I should pass `{'vintrin': Vintrin.objects.latest()}` into my context and render it in a template `{{ vintrin.image.url }}`

Answer (score 5):

You could also implement `latest()`:

```
Image.objects.latest()
Image.objects.latest('attr')
```

In a template

```
{{ object_list.latest }}
```

You can implement it by adding an attribute to the model `Meta` class:

```
class Image(models.Model):
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    # other attrs

    class Meta:
        app_label = '<app_name>'
        get_latest_by = 'date_created'
```

Comment: I've updated my question with more details, would you please check?

Comment: You are trying to iterate a single object in your template, which won't work. This returns a single object: `vitrins = Vitrin.objects.all().reverse()[0]`. Why did you want the latest object in the first place if you still want to iterate multiple objects in a template?

Comment: I just need last entry (vitrin.image) show up in index.html page not multiple items. What should I do?

Comment: Pass `{'vintrin': Vintrin.objects.latest()}` into your context and render it in a template `{{ vintrin }}`

Answer (score 3):

In view code:

```
Image.objects.all().reverse()[0]
```

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/models/querysets/#reverse

In template:

```
{{ images|last }}
```

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/templates/builtins/#last
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/4730729/1163989

**Update:**

This should work:

```
<div class='vitrin'>
    {% with vitrins|last as last %}
        <img src="{{ last.image.url }}" height="550">    
    {% endwith %}    
</div>
```

Comment: it didn't work for me, I've updated my question with more details.