# How to get the last value stored in a column in Flask SQLAlchemy and display it using jinja

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, jinja2, flask-sqlalchemy

I am making an application in flask where the user is able to create tasks. I am trying to implement a feature where the user can preview their last task which they created. What i need to do is only grab the last element in the table which stores the tasks rather then getting all of them.

```
{% for task in user.tasks %}

 {{ task.text}}

{% endfor%}
```

Above is an example where i retrieve all the tasks that the user has made. The issue is that since this is a for loop, it goes through each task and displays it.

Below is the outcome of this code when displayed in the front-end

```
"Task 1: Delete all files Task 2: Do further research Task 3: Show results on report"
```

How will i go about retrieving only the last task "Task 3: Show results on report" using jinja in flask

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4730629/15368978) answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work

```
{{ user.tasks[-1].text }}
```

Comment: unfortunately it didn't work

Comment: Is user.tasks a list type object?